# ionic2: ion-toggle not toggling

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this `ionic2` modal content:

```
<ion-toolbar class="android-attr" primary>
  <ion-title>
    Search Settings
  </ion-title>
  <ion-buttons start>
    <button (click)="dismiss()">
      <span primary showWhen="ios">Cancel</span>
      <ion-icon name='close' showWhen="android"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <h2>Search by tags</h2>
      <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      <ion-icon name="trash" item-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Use my current location</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle checked="true"></ion-toggle>
      <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div padding>
    <button primary block>Apply</button>
  </div>  
</ion-content>
```

Problem is here neither `ion-toggle` nor `ion-checkbox` toggling. I have simply added to html.

Comment: I copy/paste your code in my ionic2 app and your `<ion-toggle>` is working on my side :/

Can you provide a plunker example with more code ?

Comment: yah this my whole code. am not doing anything other than what i have posted here.

Comment: I mean, if you can reproduce this bug on a plunker with your code, then I may debug it. I can't reproduce your debug on my side.

Comment: is that working on your android mobile ?